# Drupal7 Solr Search | Views | No Results Template (?)

Tags: solr, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm using Drupal 7's Solr Search Views module to display my search results.

However, when there are no results, there is no message that displays and i can't figure out how to set one and/or where to find the setting that displays it.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the result I wanted by modifying the 'views-view--viewName.tpl.php' like so:

**Original (was not showing anything when $empty or no results):**

```
<?php if ($rows): ?>
    <?php print $rows; ?>
<?php elseif ($empty): ?>
    <?php print $empty; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**New (shows custom message when no results are found):**

```
<?php if ($rows): ?>
    <?php print $rows; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <h2>There are no results for this term. Please refine your search.</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The big difference is the change from 'elseif ($empty):' to a simple 'else:'.